# Override prepareForSegue from NSToolbar

Tags: macos, cocoa, swift, segue

I have an NSToolbar with an NSToolbarItem in it. The item segues to show a second view controller, and I want to be able to set the represented object of the view controller before the segue which means I need to override `prepareForSegue` somewhere.

I don't know which class will receive the `prepareForSegue` call. It doesn't appear to be calling in any of the other view controllers (This wouldn't make sense anyway).

So - where do I override `prepareForSegue` or do I have to do this some other way?

Comment: it should be the one that is active on the screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to subclass `NSWindowController` and put code there, like this:

```
import Cocoa

class MyWindowController: NSWindowController {    

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: NSStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if segue.identifier == "mySegue" {
            // Do whatever you want
        }
    }
}
```

And set the class of window controller in the interface builder to be `MyWindowController`.

Comment: This is how I ended up doing it - although getting the info from one view controller to the window controller is a pain :'(